# Fullcalendar event title is not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

My calendar uses the fullcalendar plugin.It shows a popupwindow to create an event but after enter the event title,it willn't display the eventtitle on the calendar.Here the renderEvent is invoking.Please give me a solution

```
var calendar = $('#datepicker');
calendar.fullCalendar
({
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    defaultEventMinutes: 60,
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) 
    {

        dialogBox=$("#dialog").dialog({

        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 1000
        },

        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                name=$("#name").val();
                startTime=$("#time-start").val();
                endTime= $("#time-end").val();
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',{title:name, start:startTime,end:endTime ,allDay:allDay},true );
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                //createEvent=false;
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        position: [jsEvent.pageX,  jsEvent.pageY]

      });
        $("#time-start").val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'hh:mmtt'));
        $("#time-end").val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'hh:mmtt')); 
        if(jsEvent.title == undefined)
        {

             $("#name").val("");
        }
        else
        {

             $("#name").val(jsEvent.title);
        }
        dialogBox.dialog("open");

    },
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        console.log('event click');
    },
    header: 
    {
        left: "prev,next today",
        center: "title",
        right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
    },
    editable: true
});
});
```

html code

```
 <div class="divCalendar">
    <div id="datepicker" style="margin: 35px;"></div>
    <div id="dialog" style="display:none" title="Alert"> 
           <div id="dialog-inner">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all  title"><br>
            <span class="inline"><input type="text" name="time" id="time-start" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></span>
            <span class="inline"><input type="text" name="time" id="time-end" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></span>
           </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Here is my fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/3ckkn/      But popup is not working in fiddile

Comment: After page refresh ,event is displayed correct?

Comment: I tried the plugin and used "selectable.html" page is properly showing event title as soon as i Create event.Plz try fresh download again.And dont lie to any1 and waste time

Comment: No,its not getting(event title)

Comment: What "title" are you trying to get? The `jsEvent` does not have a `title` property. See [Event Object](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/domevent.shtml).

Comment: Please look in to this http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

Comment: But `dayClick` is passing a `jsEvent`, not a calendar event: [dayClick](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/dayClick/), because you are not clicking on an event.